# Logparser error when used with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, event-log, logparser

I'm trying to use Log Parser within PowerShell to export a Windows Evtx log file to CSV:

```
$logparser = "c:\program files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2\logparser.exe"
$allArgs = ("SELECT * INTO c:\logs\logs.csv FROM c:\logs\logs.evtx", "-i:evt", "-o:csv")
$ps = Start-Process -FilePath $logparser -ArguementList $allArgs -Wait -Passthru -NoNewWindow;
$ps.WaitForExit()
$ps.ExitCode;
```

But when I run this I get an error:

> Error: detected extra argument "*" after query

The error code is 13. I tried putting the paths in single quotes and running it from the same directory as the logs but it keeps returning the same error.

Comment: does
 `$allArgs = @('SELECT * INTO c:\logs\logs.csv FROM c:\logs\logs.evtx -i:evt -o:csv')`
 work?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I tried it a few ways but it always comes back with the same error,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to preserve the double quotes around the query string, otherwise it won't be recognized as a single argument by the spawned process.

Putting the query string (with double quotes) in single quotes might work:

```
$allArgs = '"SELECT * INTO c:\logs\logs.csv FROM c:\logs\logs.evtx"',
           "-i:evt",
           "-o:csv"
```

However, a much simpler solution to the problem would be to avoid `Start-Process` entirely and use the call operator (`&`) instead:

```
$logparser = "c:\program files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2\logparser.exe"
$query = "SELECT * INTO c:\logs\logs.csv FROM c:\logs\logs.evtx"

& $logparser -i:evt -o:csv $query
```

Comment: Thanks, I went with the second option and it worked perfectly.